# downcasting series or dataframe element by element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1.0, 1.5],
        [2.2, 3.0]
    ])
```

---

I want to downcast the individual elements to int if they are equal. I understand that each column will end up as object type. That's OK.

[image]

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    2 non-null object
1    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 112.0+ bytes
```

Comment: this is non idiomatic and non performant, so no reason to do this

Comment: @Jeff I didn't ask for performant.  This is simple convenience for reporting.  I wanted to convert to strings further down the line and put into other things.  I determined this was the minimal example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `dtype` to `object` first, then you can use a mask to overwrite the values of interest using `astype(int)` on the df assuming all columns are numeric:

```
In [120]:
df = df.astype(object)
df[df == df.astype(int)] = df.astype(int)
df

Out[120]:
     0    1
0    1  1.5
1  2.2    3
```

Without the cast the assignment stays as float

You can see that the individual types are changed:

```
In [123]:
df.applymap(type)

Out[123]:
                 0                1
0    <class 'int'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'float'>    <class 'int'>
```

Comment: when i check `type(df.at[0,0])` it gives me `float` - do you know why? Is it `.at[]` - who is doing additional casting

Comment: @MaxU sorry I get `int` are you assigning the result back?

Comment: yes, i am. `df.dtypes` returns  `object` for both columns

Comment: Well then I don't know because this works fine for me using pandas `0.19.0` and numpy `1.11.0` python 64-bit 3.4

Comment: Interesting - I'm using Python 3.5.2 64-bit, Pandas 0.19.1, NumPy 1.11.1

Comment: So what do you see in the output and for `df.loc[0,0]` do you see `1` outputted?

Comment: i see `1.0`, but when i just print `df` it shows me `1` at that cell

Comment: could be a bug, I'd have to upgrade my pandas and then my numpy separately to see which maybe the cause here but this definitely works fine for me so I don't know

Comment: @MaxU so presumably you see only `float` when you do `df.applymap(type)` after the conversion?

Comment: please see my "answer"